# How to search by first name and last name using get api in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, crud

I want to search by first name and last name using the get api. I have already implemented this and it works but it also works when at least one of the input values is correct instead of all. I want it to display the table row only if both first name and last name entered are correct. How do I do this?

```
export class SearchDeleteComponent implements OnInit {

  users:any;

constructor(private service: NewUserService, private route:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let resp=this.service.getUsers();
    resp.subscribe((data)=>this.users=data);
  }
public findUserByName(){
   

   let resp=this.service.getUserByFirstName(this.firstName);
    resp.subscribe((data)=>this.users=data);

    let lName=this.service.getUserByLastName(this.lastName);
    lName.subscribe((data)=>this.users=data);
```

```
 <form>
             
        
               <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
                                        
                    <input class="search-query" type="text"  placeholder="Search With first name" size="50"  name="name"  [(ngModel)]="firstName"/>
    
                </div>
             
                                <br>
                                <div class="input-group col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
                                    
                                    <input class="search-query" type="text"  placeholder="Search With last name" size="50"  name="name"  [(ngModel)]="lastName"/>
                    
                                </div>
</div>
</div>
</forms>
```

Comment: If this API is yours you should probably write a method that will search with all those parameters at once. Taking values of both inputs

Comment: could you give me an example

Comment: I cant help you without knowing your backend code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal opinion is, that you add another endpoint which accepts both parameters and returns your expected output. That should be the preferred solution.

If you really want to stick with your single request, I suggest the usage of forkJoin together with lodashs intersection

```
const response = forkJoin([
  this.service.getUserByFirstName(this.firstName),
  this.service.getUserByLastName(this.lastName)
]);

response.subscribe(
  ([firstNameUsers, lastNameUsers]) => this.users = lodash.intersectionWith(firstNameUsers, lastNameUsers, lodash.isEqual)
);
```

Or you execute only one request and filter the response with the second parameter

```
const response = this.service.getUserByFirstName(this.firstName).pipe(
  map(users => users.filter(user => user.lastName === this.lastName)),
);
response.subscribe(data => this.users = data);
```